# Regex doesnt work, how should it be formulated?

Tags: java, regex, string

I Want to know if a String consists only of the same character except at the last index, it can be any other possible character except the character that's leading. 
For Example:  "FFFFFFFl" matches the pattern, but "FlFFFF" not.

If the String is only one Character, it should output false.

I have this code, but actually it's not working:

```
String dance = "FFFFFl";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(dance.charAt(0) + "{" + (dance.length()-1) + "}\\w^" + dance.charAt(0));
Matcher m = p.matcher(dance);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

This outputs "false" even though it should be true.
I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: `^` means start of a String, but you have characters before the start of the string which shouldn't work as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: What should be result for Strings with only one character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.)\\1*+.$");
```

Match:

```
AF
AAAAAF
```

Don't match:

```
AAAA
AFFFF
```

Comment: @Christoph: can you provide an example? I'll edit my answer to provide examples on which I tested it.

Comment: trouble is you took non-matching group

Comment: @Deduplicator Ah, true, I blindly changed it after testing with a matching one. Fixed.

Comment: +1 but it would be nice to describe idea on which this regex works (the one about [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `*+`). BTW since we are going to use `matches` method which by default checks if entire string can be matched with regex you don't need `^` or `$` anchors.

Comment: Actually I would also really appreciate an explanation of how this regex works.

Comment: @Christoph to put it shortly, quantifiers like `*`, `+`, `{min, max}` are greedy so they will try to match maximal possible substring but in case they will match to long substring they will allow backtracking so lets say you have regex `b*b` and data `bbbbb`. At first `b*` will match all 5 `b`s but since there is another `b` in regex which needs to be matched `b*` will backtrack to match only 4 firs `b`s and let last `b` be matched by last `b` in regex.

Comment: @Christoph With possessive quantifier (the one with additional `+` like `*+`) backtracking is impossible so regex `b*+b` will never match `bbbbb` because all `b`s will be consumed (possessed) by `b*` so last `b` in regex will never find its match (as mentioned backtracking is impossible) making regex unable to find its match. This idea was used here, where instead of `b*` we used first letter in String. `\\1*+` will consume all same characters as first character in string letting `.` match only something which is different that first character (otherwise it would be consumed by `\\1*+`

Comment: Wow thanks, great explanation! I really got the Point of the quantifiers. Now i also understand the regex above. Thank you a lot Pshemo!

Answer (score 0):

Pattern: `"^(.)\\1*+.$"`

See [java reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)

Answer (score 0):

The following does not work I just found out:

```
if (dance.matches("(.)\\1*(!\\1)"))
```

where `\\1` is the first group (the first char).

Your approach:

```
dance.charAt(0) + "{" + (dance.length()-1) + "}[^" + dance.charAt(0) + "]"
```